# How to prevent CMake from installing .lib files

Tags: windows, cmake, java-native-interface

I am cross-compiling a JNI DLL on Windows using MSVC + CMake and I noticed that it is producing a `.lib` file on install. I am using `add_library(mylibname SHARED ...)` and `install(TARGETS mylibname DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})` to create and install the shared library. Is there a way to prevent this file from being installed as it is not needed for JNI libraries at runtime?

Comment: `.lib` file is installed as part of `ARCHIVE` clause of [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-targets) command. You may those clauses for `install` command which you want and omit others. Note, however, that without `.lib` file no project can be **built** against your library. (But if a project is already built, then it could use your library for **run**.) As for `:cmake_mode_t` files, it is completely different story(see e.g. https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19739) and it should be asked separately.

Comment: Adding `RUNTIME` to my `install(TARGETS mylibname RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})` command appears to resolve the `.lib` problem.  This is a JNI library so it should never be linked against or otherwise used outside of its final form.  As far as the `:cmake_mode_t` files go, that link helps explain why they are showing up but not how to disable that behavior.  I need to cross compile several of these targets but I don't need these permissions...  I am not packaging for debian or any other *nix system.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the link neither explains you case nor resolves it. It is just for demonstration that installing (or not installing) `.lib` file is completely **irrelevant** to creating (or not creating): `cmake_mode_t` file. On Stack Overflow we tent to have a question post about the **single problem**, so it is better to split your question post into two. Also, for me. JNI nature of your project seems to be very relevant to the both problems, Consider adding this notion into the question(s) post.